# VMWare Converter - Exclude files/folder

Tags: vmware-converter

Is it possible in VMWare Converter when converting P2V, to exclude certain files and folders...

I have some large folders (temp / downloads / iso's / backups) I want to exclude from the conversion.

I don't want to exclude a whole drive, just certain folders.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the only way to exclude the folder is to not have the folder there; move them to another location and convert. Otherwise you'll have to convert the machine and delete them from the resulting VM.

Comment: Couldn't find anything about exclusions, so I'm affraid those are the only options :( I wanted to save space/bandwidth and time by excluding unneeded large folders. Too bad... (it's seems such a basic feature)

Comment: Depends on the implementation. P2V usually assumes you want to move a server in order to shut down the physical system, not selectively move things. Or if you're shutting it down you already moved stuff off that you don't want there.

Comment: I also don't know if it's going to check the sectors regardless of whether there's data there or not, just to be thorough in the conversion.

Comment: Very good point Bart, I'm going to bring a physical machine offline. So it makes no sense to leave those folders there. You're right about that I should move my downloads/backups/iso's to another location. Going to do that before the conversion to save bandwidth and time. Tempory folders and large log folders i don't need, need to be deleted before the conversion. Thanks all.

Comment: In doing a physical to virtual migration it's always a good idea (if you have proper backups) to clean the system as part of prep. I also have run a defrag just for good measure, to help cluster up some of the data...maybe it's naive, but I thought the more contiguous "blank space" on the drive the better. Or at least it made me feel a little better about cleaning up the system.